# Num Rows always ='s 1 for some reason. QUICK FIX

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-num-rows

I don't know if i am doing it right, this is what I got:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $items = mysqli_num_rows($row); 
}
```

It always sets $items = to 1 for some reason.

Here is my mysqli_query...

```
$top10_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='$userid'";
                        $result = mysqli_query($cxn, $top10_query) or die("Couldn't execute query.");
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Comment: What were you expecting it to do? 1,2,3,4..? 4,4,4,4? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `$row` only contains one row so....

```
$items = mysqli_num_rows($result)
```

should give you the correct number of items

---

Anyway, why are you doing that in a loop? The number of rows is constant...

Comment: $items = mysqli_num_rows($result);

I had that, it gives me $items = 1.

Comment: @Rick Bross: well, of course it returns 1. I'm assuming the ID is unique for each user, so your query does indeed only return 1 result. What would you expect as result?

Comment: output the amount of rows WHERE userid='$userid' 

does it just count the primary id, or something?